# How to set shadow outline (solid) around UIImageView text in Swift?

Tags: swift, uiimageview

I want to set shadow outline (solid) around UIImageView text.

I tried below code: -

```
class BottomToolBarImageView: UIImageView {

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        layer.shadowColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 5.0, height: 5.0)
        layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
        layer.shadowRadius = 0.0
    }
}
```

But this is not working as I required. Please suggest. Thanks in advance.

I required output like: -

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, you should add border to image view, instead of shadow.

```
class BottomToolBarImageView: UIImageView {

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        layer.borderWidth = 4.0
        layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.height/2
    }
}
```

This should work. 
P.S Kindly change cornerRadius according to required output.